# I'm getting an error when I ran mysql_secure_installation

Tags: mysql

I keep getting the following error on running **`sudo mysql_secure_installation`**

> ... Failed! Error: SET PASSWORD has no significance for user
> 'root'@'localhost' as the authentication method used doesn't store
> authentication data in the MySQL server. Please consider using ALTER
> USER instead if you want to change authentication parameters.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Login as a root user without using any password

```
sudo mysql
```

Then use the following command to change the authentication parameter:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by 'mynewpassword'
```

where `mynewpassword` is the new password you have set for root user, it would help to access and run installation again.

Run again `mysql_secure_installation` to secure MySQL

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

once asked, enter the new set password for root user you recently did.

See [MySQL Authentication Method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/page_protocol_connection_phase_authentication_methods.html)